# Exporting a validator for Angular reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-custom-validators

I am trying to create a `ValidatorFn` that will be used in several components which represent custom reactive form controls. My initial idea was to generate a TypeScript class, create a public static function (or several) there and then just use it like so: `myFGroup.setValidators(ReactiveValidators.myValidator)`.

The problem is, although I imported this `ReactiveValidators` class in the **app.module** and added it to `declarations: []`, I still get the favorite error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/validators/reactive-validators'

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, is this approach even a good one at all?

Comment: Did you add `@Component` inside your `ReactiveValidators` class ? Did you add `ReactiveValidators` in a module's `declaration` ? If so, remove it. It is not an Angular Component.

Comment: No, I didn't add @Component. Thanks for pointing that out. But how can I export that ValidatorFn or the class that wraps it correctly? I'm not keen on pasting it in several files :)

Comment: using `myFGroup.setValidators(ReactiveValidators.myValidator)` will work, where `ReactiveValidators` is in its own file anywhere in your app.

Comment: That's what I thought - and did. I even generated a `ReactiveValidators` class using `ng generate class`, but I still get the error above.

Comment: Can you show your component using the validator, your `ReactiveValidators`, and your module then ?

Comment: I figured it out while editing the answer... the correct import statement is `import { maxInputLengthValidator } from '../../validators/reactive-validators'`. Notice the relative path. And, for some reason, VS Code auto import uses absolute path, the one in the error message. I fixed the path, now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dzenesiz glad to hear, I posted your comments as an answer so that it could help other colleagues in future if they face same sort of issue. Thanks

Comment: Ok, just fix the formatting so the import statement is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A ValidatorFun is just a function, which is not required to be in any class. You can simply create a ts file with exported Validator functions.

```
export const myValidator: ValidatorFn = /* ... */;
export const myOtherValidator: ValidatorFn = /* ... */;
export function myJustAnotherValidator(/* ... */) { /* ... */ }
```

And you can import them like
`import { myValidator, myOtherValidator } from  '../mypath/reactive-validators';`
Or
`import * as ReactiveValidators from  '../mypath/reactive-validators';`

No module import required

Comment: I tried that. Created a `reactive-validators.ts` file, and, istead of making it a class, just exported a function like so: `export const maxInputLengthValidator: ValidatorFn = function() {...}`... I still get the error _cannot find module `src/app/validators/reactive-validators`_ .

Answer (score 0):

As per @dzenesiz he figured out issue, the issue was in importing syntax.

The correct import statement is import.

```
{ maxInputLengthValidator } from '../../validators/reactive-validators'
```

Notice the relative path. And, for some reason, VS Code auto import uses absolute path, the one in the error message. I fixed the path, now it works